# how are QActions deleted

Tags: c++, qt

I am pretty confused about one thing in Qt:

You often add new actions to QMenu like this:

```
menu.addAction(new QAction("this is a menu"));
```

so you are creating a new object but who is deleting it? According to https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25717 the parent object should take care of that but... does it always happen? What if I didn't put any parent object in constructor? What if I deleted the object myself, will parent object SEGFAULT as it deletes object that was already deleted?

Even default code that is created by qt creator is creating object called `ui` in constructor and deletes it in destructor. That is what I was doing for my own objects that I created on the fly, but surprisingly, it never crashed. I just figured out that all the time I probably shouldn't have even delete them myself?

What is a proper way to deal with this? Does it apply for all QObjects that had a pointer to parent object in constructor?

Bonus question: if these objects are deleted by parent's destructor, does it mean that if parent is main window of application that is closed on exit only, that all new objects will just leak until the application is closed?

Comment: If you do not set the parent you have to delete the object yourself. Some objects take ownership of their child objects on addition - such cases described in Qt documentation.

Comment: See [Object trees & ownership](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Comment: Qt's ownership system was designed before C++11 and rvalue references. Compiler won't help you in spotting ownership-related mistakes. You can only find out details about who and when takes the ownership of an object in Qt documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `QObject` to be automatically deleted, you must specify a parent. Most derived classes provide for this in one or more of their constructor parameters.

The `QAction` you created above does not have a parent so it will not be deleted when the `QMenu` is destroyed. To make it do so, change the line to be:

```
menu.addAction(new QAction("this is a menu", &menu));
```

This is not advisable though since `QAction` is an implementation of the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) so it is intended to be used in more places than a `QMenu` and thus its lifespan must not be tied to that of the `QMenu`. A simple example would be as a button on a `QToolBar`.

For this reason, the `QMenu` does not make itself the parent of the `QAction` when you add it.

Some other derived classes of `QObject` do indeed do this so it is not always necessary to explicitly assign a parent yourself.

One common example is `QMainWindow`. Whenever you assign a `QWidget` using `setCentralWidget()`, the main window will take ownership and force itself to be the parent of the new central widget, even if you made some other object that widget's parent.

Comment: ok, so if I was adding and removing items from menu during the run of application, these would get deleted only when I exit the application? Isn't that a memory leak?

Comment: I am talking about case when I put the main window as parent to these new objects

Comment: also is it safe to delete the object which has some parent?

Comment: If you were adding `QAction` items to a menu like in the question, then yes, you have a memory leak. If there is a parent, then no.

Comment: It is safe to delete a child with a parent because `QObject`s are smart enough to let each other know when they're being deleted. Parents will not try and double-delete.